# Missing Headers when they are present

Tags: c, github, makefile, header, openssl

For some reason, on my OS X machine I can't MAKE any Github project. See, if in the C code is an "include openssh/whatever.h" or openssl, then even if I checked and the header is in the folder, It simply say: e.g.:

```
fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
```

I tried SUDO, I tried reinstalling  / updating openssl / ssh, same issue over and over again. Seem to have an issue seeing these headers when they are clearly present.

For reference, I tried compiling https://github.com/xerub/ibex

Comment: Do you have the `openssl-dev` package, or whatever name it has on OS X?

Comment: I have the standard OpenSSL you obtain via brew command in terminal.

Comment: I am not familiar with OSX, but on Linux distributions there are usually the basic "runtime" packages, providing the libraries for applications using them and the `dev` packages containing the sources/headers if you want to compile something using them. So you need the latter.

Comment: On OS X I have a folder with all these headers (.h) files.

Comment: OK, in that case you have some other issue.

Comment: Try adding `-I/path/to/the/folder/containing/openssl` to the `CFLAGS` in the `Makefile`.

Comment: I already have a couple of CFLAGS but none of them seem to have a path to tha. I simply make a new CFLAG = -I [...] ?

Comment: `CFLAG +=`. It will add to the existing ones. Don't include the `openssl` folder itself, just the path up to it.

Comment: Please show the command that's producing the error. Please state exactly where you installed OpenSSL.

Comment: @Chill-Out Music - you need to provide the requested information or risk having the question closed. We can't provide useful information by guessing at things.

Comment: the openssl is in /usr/local/opt/openssl

Comment: the command is "MAKE"

Comment: the referenced code on github does not have any reference to `openssl` directory/library in the `makefile` nor any section in  `stript.ld`  So you need to add the appropriate information.  Note: the `script.ld` file seems to be missing the `MEMORY { ... }` statement.

Comment: the referenced code contains dozens of the problem: "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]"   It should be noted: the `-W` option suppresses all warnings.   I.E. You should not use that option.  Suggest: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99`

Comment: in the `Makefile` this line: `ARFLAGS = crus` creates a problem/warning message.  Suggest using: `ARFLAGS := vrs`

Comment: int the cache.S file, the gcc assember does not recognize @ as a valid start of comment. Suggest using / or // or #